# SQLAlchemy instance already exists but I have just used the instance once what should i do?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

somehow this error is showing up which was not there and i am not able to resolve it

```
C:\Users\dhruv\OneDrive\Desktop\flask - Copy>python app.py        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dhruv\OneDrive\Desktop\flask - Copy\app.py", line 23, in <module>
    db.init_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 253, in init_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead.

C:\Users\dhruv\OneDrive\Desktop\flask - Copy>
```

the code segment of user database model

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abc'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/files'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
migrate = Migrate(app,db)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
```

i tried removing db.init_app(app) which was something that i should have done but now also i still have the error and its not getting resolved